# Scrum process template changes not recognized

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2013

I'm trying to add new activities to the Activity field in the Task work item.  I've downloaded the process template locally and added a few new LISTITEM elements.  Here's the updated section:

```
      <FIELD name="Activity" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="String" reportable="dimension">
        <SUGGESTEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="Database" />
          <LISTITEM value="Deployment" />
          <LISTITEM value="Design" />
          <LISTITEM value="Development" />
          <LISTITEM value="Documentation" />
          <LISTITEM value="Investigation" />
          <LISTITEM value="Level of Effort" />
          <LISTITEM value="Planning" />
          <LISTITEM value="Reporting" />
          <LISTITEM value="Requirements" />
          <LISTITEM value="Research" />
          <LISTITEM value="Testing" />
        </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
      </FIELD>
```

I then uploaded the modified process templates back.  However, in both VS2013 and Team Web Access I do not see the new values in the Activity dropdown.  Is there some sort of refresh or validation process I need to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading the process template only changes the *template*, not the process you are using - so new projects will have this, but your existing projects need updating.

You need to use the [`witadmin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) command line to update the work item type definition in the project you are working in.

Something like:

```
witadmin importwitd /f:Task.xml /p:MyProject /collection:http://tfs:8080/DefaultCollection
```

Will update the WITD in your project.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I figured that out about an hour after I posted this.  I should have come back and answered this myself but I got sidetracked.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I'm sure it will help others.